# Подсчитать среднее значеие элементов в массиве

Tags: c++, массивы, borland

Рост учеников класса представлен в виде массива. Определить средний рост мальчиков и девочек. Вывести сообщение кто выше девочки или мальчики.

Я понял, что нужно задать массив (3 сверху - мальчики, 3 снизу - девочки), вычислить среднее значения и сравнить, но у меня постоянно какие-то ошибки. Не могу даже нормально вывести массив на экран, хотя делал по образцу:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
std::string students[6]={
 "170", "171", "189",
 "160", "156", "159"};
 cout<<students;
 return 0;
}
```

Совсем не могу понять в чём дело то.

Comment: 1. как ты отличаешь мальчиков от девочек?

Comment: Да это просто же цифры. Номера 1,2,3 - рост мальчиков. 4,5,6 - рост девочек

Comment: Я не могу понять, почему он не хочет выводить массив на экран. Я написал команду "cout", однако он не хочет выводить на экран результаты, хотя делал по образцу

Comment: @Treaq, когда задаете вопрос, описывайте (кроме своих пожеланий) **что реально видите на экране** (можно не все, а только относящиеся к делу сообщения).

В Вашем случае (для начала) надо бы сообщить, что *программа ***просто*** не компилируется*.

(или (если компилируется, а ее вывод отличается от ожидаемого) привести в вопросе актуальный код).

--

Это к ответу @fori1ton об отсутствующей фигурной скобке.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот самые серьёзные ошибки:

1. Пропустили открывающуюб фигурную скобку после `main()`
2. Если вы надеетесь, что строка `cout << students;` выведет содержимое массива, то вы ошибаетесь. Переменная `students` - это указатель на начало массива, поэтому выведется только адрес в памяти, по которому располагается первый элемент массива. Если вы хотите вывести элементы массива, придётся сделать цикл и выводить по одному.

И ещё пара замечаний помеьче:

1. Если вы прописали `using namespace std;`, то явно указывать пространсво имён `std` при объявлении массива `string` не нужно.
2. Всё-таки, будет лучше, если роста мальчиков и девочек будут храниться в разных массивах.
3. Почему вы храните числа в `string`? Особенно если вам нужно посчитать их среднее арифметическое. `float` или на крайняк `int` подошёл бы куда лучше.

Comment: всё делал по образцу, а именно "using namespace std;" и "string" :c

Спасибо, попробую

Comment: @Treaq, попробуйте не делать по образцу, а сначала почитать какой-нибудь учебник по языку, вникнуть в его основные конструкции, и только потом писать на нём. Делая по образцу вы ничему не научитесь.

Answer (score 0):

> av_boy :=
> (students[1]+students[2]+students[3])/3;
>
> writeln("Средний возраст мальчиков=
> ",av_boy);

по аналогии и для девочек.

Comment: Это я и сам знаю (кстати, вы на паскале записали, не?), я не могу понять почему даже в моём коде ошибка и как это исправить. Мне нужно найти через массив, желательно весь код, а не вырезками.

Comment: ну так ты хоть напиши какие ошибки, мы же не волшебники)

Comment: i019.radikal.ru/1406/33/ecd4f00740det.jpg
Я думал в компилятор запихнёшь, всё таки картинка не то)

Comment: Ошибку компиляции исправит добавление первой/второй строкой такого

    #include <iostream>

Но навряд ли то, что выведет программа, можно считать правильным результатом.

Comment: дык оно же есть. Самым первым стоит

Comment: на  картинке его нет.

Хотя это может быть ещё следствие древнего компилятора.

Answer (score 0):

```
int students[6] = {170, 171, 189, 160, 156, 159};
float boy = 0, girl = 0;
cout<<"Мальчики:";
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    printf(" %d",students[i]);
    boy += students[i];
}
boy /= 3;
printf("\nСредний рост мальчиков: %f\n", boy);
...
if (boy > girl) cout<<"Мальчики выше";
...
```